# nginx req_limit does not work in regex location

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

i have nginx file part like this

```
http {
   limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=limit:1m rate=10r/s;

   server {
     listen 443 ssl;
     server_name domain.temp;
     root "/var/www";
     index index.php;
     location ~* ^/([0-9]+)$ {
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)$ /blank.php?id=$1 last;
        limit_req zone=limit burst=3;
      }
      location /apply/ {
            limit_req zone=limit burst=6;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the `/apply/` does work as it should and is limited by 6 bursts and the rest slow

but `^/([0-9]+)$` does not work and does not have any effect

but if i move `limit_req zone=limit burst=3;` into `server{}` block it works on everything inside the block from locations but i want it to work on `^/([0-9]+)$` block only

Comment: What is the exact URL you are trying to test and where the limit doesn't work?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen `^/([0-9]+)$` any link in this pattern like `/12345` or `/6789` but dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely related to `rewrite ^/([0-9]+)$ /blank.php?id=$1 last;` directive. [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) states:

> `last` stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives and starts a search for a new location matching the changed URI;

It can be that the `rewrite` is processed before `limit_req` in nginx, therefore nginx starts to process `/blank.php` and since there is no `location` block matching this request, no limit is assigned.

If this is the reason for limit not working, then getting around it is somewhat complex. `location` blocks only match the URL path without the query arguments. So, you would need to have:

```
location /blank.php {
    limit_reqzone=limit burst=3;
    # PHP processing directives from "location ~ \.php$" block
}
```

However, this would match all requests to `blank.php`. If you want to restrict matching to requests with only `id` query argument, you need a more complex setup:

```
http {
    # If there is "id" argument in query arguments and it is a number, use "limit" zone. By default, use "nolimit" zone.
    map $arg_id $limit_zone {
        ~ ^[0-9]+$ limit;
        default nolimit;
    }

    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=limit:1m rate=10r/s;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=nolimit:1m rate=1000r/s;

    server {
        location /blank.php {
            limit_req zone=$limit_zone burst=6;
            # PHP processing directives from "location ~ \.php$" block
        }
        location /apply {
            limit_req zone=limit burst=6;
    }
}
```

I don't see a direct way to map request from rate limited / not rate limited directly.

Therefore we need to use `map` to select a limit zone, and the "nolimit" zone just has such high limits that it is essentially a zone without limites.